# What are aliases like after compilation in C++?

Tags: c++, alias

Are aliases regarded as adentical to its original after compilation?
In other words, is alias a sugar syntax that only remains during coding?

Comment: What do you mean? There's no alias in C++

Comment: Yes, type aliases (created with `using` and `typedef`) are just convenient shorthand for the original.

Comment: Sorry for my badly described question. Chen's answer is what I've hoped for, yet Friesner's also helped. My thanks to both JeremyFriesner and @RaymondChen !  Xiexie!

Comment: If you mean type aliases and `typedef`s, then they are only relevant at compile time.   For example, `typedef  int Foo` doesn't create a type named `Foo` that is distinct from an `int` - it just creates another name for an `int`.   So, if there are two declarations of a function (say, `void x(Foo)` and `void x(int)` ) they declare one function (which accepts an `int`), rather than producing two distinct overloads of `x()` for `Foo` and `int` arguments.

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) says:

> A type alias declaration introduces a name which can be used as a synonym for the type denoted by type-id. It does not introduce a new type and it cannot change the meaning of an existing type name. There is no difference between a type alias declaration and typedef declaration.

If you see some code like this in [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3a3Tb7oqY):

```
struct VeryLongNamedType {
    int n;

    VeryLongNamedType(int n){
        this->n = n;
    }
};

int main(){
    using Type = VeryLongNamedType;

    Type a(8);
    VeryLongNamedType b(9);
}
```

You'll notice that the using statement doesn't produce any instruction. Even when constructing, both lines call the same constructor.

Short answer: It's just syntactic sugar.